# How to catch Chrome's net:: exceptions using jQuery.get?

Tags: javascript, jquery

More specifically, I'm looking to catch `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`, but in general how does one catch errors like this?

`$.get(example_valid_url).error(function(req, status, e){})` doesn't have any of the information, and the status code of the response is `0`.

Wrapping the code in a try...catch doesn't help either, as the error isn't caught.

Comment: is that your actual url?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans no. I'm just looking for information on catching errors prefixed with `net::`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the $.get example is probably misleading (because if that was the problem, there are other ways to do url validation before allowing a xmlhttprequest through).

`net::` errors cannot be try/caught, as they are protocol violations, rather than in-protocol responses that just aren't "http:200 OK". If you get a `net::` error, it means the code you're using is trying to do things (or is initiating things) that would break the browser if allowed through, not just the script you're currently running.